# Display all search results when web scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a list of URL's from the European Parliament's Legislative Observatory. I do not type in any search keyword in order to get all links to documents (currently 13172). I can easily scrape a list of the first 10 results which are displayed on the website using the code below. However, I want to have all links so that I would not need to somehow press the next page button. Please let me know if you know of a way to achieve this.

```
import requests, bs4, re

# main url of the Legislative Observatory's search site
url_main = 'http://www.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/search/search.do?searchTab=y'

# function gets a list of links to the procedures
def links_to_procedures (url_main):
    # requesting html code from the main search site of the Legislative Observatory
    response = requests.get(url_main)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text) # loading text into Beautiful Soup
    links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.procedure_title a')] # getting a list of links of the procedure title
    return links

print(links_to_procedures(url_main))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the pagination by specifying the `page` GET parameter.

First, get the results count, then calculate the number of pages to process by dividing the count on the results count per page. Then, iterate over pages one by one and collect the links:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/search/search.do?searchTab=y')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

# get the results count
num_results = soup.find('span', class_=re.compile('resultNum')).text
num_results = int(re.search('(\d+)', num_results).group(1))
print "Results found: " + str(num_results)

results_per_page = 50
base_url = "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/search/result.do?page={page}&rows=%s&sort=d&searchTab=y&sortTab=y&x=1411566719001" % results_per_page

links = []
for page in xrange(1, num_results/results_per_page + 1):
    print "Current page: " + str(page)

    url = base_url.format(page=page)
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    links += [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.procedure_title a')]

print links
```